# Python what does it mean "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'has_key' "

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I would like to ask what does it mean "AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'has_key'"
Here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "D:\Projects\GoogleAppEngine\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\webapp\__init__.py", line 509, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "D:\Projects\workspace\foo\src\homepage.py", line 71, in post
    country=postedcountry
  File "D:\Projects\GoogleAppEngine\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 656, in __init__
    prop.__set__(self, value)
  File "D:\Projects\GoogleAppEngine\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 2712, in __set__
    value = self.validate(value)
  File "D:\Projects\GoogleAppEngine\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\db\__init__.py", line 2742, in validate
    if value is not None and not value.has_key():
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

Let me describe a little bit more about the situation:

- First I created the models.py that has the db.Model for CMSRequest which has an attribute country that reference to the CMSCountry class

  ```
  class CMSRequest(db.Model):
    country = db.ReferenceProperty(CMSCountry, required=True)

  class CMSCountry(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
  ```
- Then, I created a bulkloader class to import the data into the CMSCountry
- In the form, user can select the country from the drop down list box, the results are posted back and save to the CMSRequest object

  ```
  def post(self):
    postedcountry = self.request.get('country')
    cmsRequest = models.CMSRequest(postedcountry)
  ```

Maybe I have found the solution to my question, it is because I have not converted the posted key of CMSCountry back to save to the CMSRequest.

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this line:

```
if value is not None and not value.has_key():
```

`value` is a unicode string.  It looks like the code is expecting it to be a `db.Model`,

(From what I can see, `has_key` is a method of `db.Model`, as well as a method of Python dictionaries, but this must be the `db.Model` one because it's being called with no arguments.)

Are you passing a string to a GAE API that expects a `db.Model`?

Comment: @Hoang: It looks like you need something along the lines of `cmsRequest = models.CMSRequest(country=models.CMSCountry(postedcountry))` (I don't know whether that's exactly the right way to get a `CMSCountry` from a string, but you see what I'm saying).

Comment: Thank Richie, based on your suggestion, I have modified the code as following:
def post(self):
  postedcountry = self.request.get('country')
  country = models.CMSCountry.get(postedcountry) 
  cmsRequest = models.CMSRequest(country)
The key of the country should be populated in the html for the options, and postedcountry will have the key of the CMSCountry.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that postedcountry is a string and not a country object.  Values retrieved from self.request.get are the string values of variables passed by the browser.

You need to look up a country object using some GQL.  Exactly how you do that will depend on what exactly the country field of your HTML form is returning , Object Key?, country name?

```
def post(self):
  postedcountry = self.request.get('country')

  # <-------- Need to look up a country here !!!!!

  cmsRequest = models.CMSRequest(country=postedcountry)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: normally "mapping" types in Python (dictionaries and dictionary like classes ... such as various types of dbm (indexed file) and some DBMS/ORM interfaces ... will implement a `has_key()` method.

Somehow you have gotten a Unicode (string) object into this statement when you were expecting to have some sort of dictionary or other mapping object reference.

In general **AttributeError** means that you have tangled up your object bindings (variable assignments).  You've given a name to some object other than the type that you intended.  (Or sometimes it means you have a typo like ".haskey()" instead of `has_key()` ... etc).

BTW: the use of `has_key()` is somewhat dated.  Normally it's better to test your containers with the Python **`in`** operator (which implicitly calls `__contains__()` --- and which works on lists, strings, and other sequences as well as mapping types).

Also `value.has_key()` would raise an error even if `value` were a dictionary since the `.has_key()` method requires an argument.

In your code I would either explicitly test for `if postedcountry is not None:` ... or I'd supply your `.get()` with an (optional) default for "postedcountry."

How do you want to handle the situation where `request` had no **postedcountry**?  Do you want to assume it's being posted from some particular default?  Force a redirection to some page that requires the user to supply a value for that form element?  Alert the Spanish Inquisition?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the traceback, it'll tell you exactly what is going on:

```
    if value is not None and not value.has_key():
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

What this says is the the `value` variable which you're using doesn't have the `has_key` attribute.  And, what it's telling you is that your `value` variable isn't a dictionary, as it looks like you're expecting...instead, it's a unicode object, which is basically a string.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to set a string to a ReferenceProperty. The 'country' field of CMSCountry is a db.ReferenceProperty, which takes a db.Key or a CMSCountry object, but you're attempting to set it to a string.

You should be doing something like this:

```
def post(self):
  postedcountry = self.request.get('country')
  country = models.CMSCountry.all().filter('name =', postedcountry)
  if not country:
    # Couldn't find the country
  else:
    cmsRequest = models.CMSRequest(country=country)
```

Please do [file a bug](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list) about the rather unhelpful error message, though.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary object's has_key() method is deprecated in 3.0 - use the "in" expression instead. If you are using the old library in 3.x, you must make code changes to accommodate it.