# jinja2 rendering issue: AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '__call__'

Tags: python, jinja2

I am trying to execute the following [filtered transaction report from the piecash project](http://piecash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/examples.html#filtered-transaction-reports):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime
import re
import os.path

from piecash import open_book


if __name__=='__main__':
    this_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    s = open_book(os.path.join(this_folder, "teste.gnucash"), open_if_lock=True)
else:
    s = open_book(os.path.join("teste.gnucash"), open_if_lock=True)

# get default currency
print(s.default_currency)

regex_filter = re.compile(u"^/Ativos/Dinheiro/Carteira")

# retrieve relevant transactions
transactions = [tr for tr in s.transactions  # query all transactions in the book/session and filter them on
                if (regex_filter.search(tr.description)  # description field matching regex
                    or any(regex_filter.search(spl.memo) for spl in tr.splits))  # or memo field of any split of transaction
                and tr.post_date.date() >= datetime.date(2016, 03, 1)]  # and with post_date no later than begin nov.

try:
    import jinja2
except ImportError:
    print("\n\t*** Install jinja2 ('pip install jinja2') to test the jinja2 template version ***\n")
    jinja2 = None

if jinja2:
    env = jinja2.Environment(trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True)
    print(env.from_string("""
    Here are the transactions for the search criteria '{{regex.pattern}}':
    {% for tr in transactions %}
    - {{ tr.post_date.strftime("%Y/%m/%d") }} : {{ tr.description }}
      {% for spl in tr.splits %}
        {{ spl.value.__abs__() }} {% if spl.value < 0 %} --> {% else %} <-- {% endif %} {{ spl.account.fullname() }} : {{ spl.memo }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    """).render(transactions=transactions,regex=regex_filter))
```

However I get the following error on the last line of the code, when trying to render the jinja2 template:

> AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute '**call**'

I found that the last answer (by @brianz) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314617/python-what-does-it-mean-attributeerror-unicode-object-has-no-attribute-has) shed some light into the problem. `transactions`is a list of unicode strings, while `regex_filter`is a compiled regex regular expression object, from which the pattern was extracted by the template in `regex.pattern`.

I tried to pass the `regex.pattern`directly without any success, trying to follow the [jinja2 api render](http://regex_filter.pattern) example.

Any ideas on what exactly am I missing?

Comment: is there any chance at all that `spl.account.fullname` is a unicode and you are trying to call it or is that not being called immediately?

Comment: Genious @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen, that was it! Thanks for your help, could you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it? I was looking into the wrong places all the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the last line of `.format()` does a lot of stuff to go wrong, specifically I noticed:

```
{{ spl.account.fullname() }}
```

which seems like the kind of name that could be an attribute or method so [I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083174/jinja2-rendering-issue-attributeerror-unicode-object-has-no-attribute-cal?noredirect=1#comment59810790_36083174) and it seems it is in fact unicode that you tried to call.  Mystery solved ;)